# Extracting a data.frame from two lists in BASE R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, loops

In my R code below, I'm trying to obtain my `desired output` in which `mpre1`,`sdpre1`,`n1` are extracted from my `aa` list when `control==FALSE` and `mpre2`,`sdpre2`,`n2` are extracted from my `aa` list when `control==TRUE`. Two other extraction indices are `outcome` and `post` which vary across `mpre1`... side and the `mpre2`... side.

The idea is that in each row of the desired output, the set of `mpre1`,`sdpre1`,`n1` elements from `aa` (see below) come from the `control==FALSE` side (`aa`) and the set of `mpre2`,`sdpre2`,`n2` elements from `aa` (see below) come from the `control==TRUE` side.

Is my desired output possible to obtain in BASE R?

```
# Desired output (4 rows x 6 columns):
#  mpre1 sdpre1 n1 mpre2 sdpre2 n2
#1  81.6   10.8 73 80.50 11.20  80 
#2  85.7   13.7 66 90.30  6.60  74 
#3  81.4   10.9 72 80.50 11.20  80
#4  90.4    8.2 61 90.30  6.60  74
```

I have tried to form a `expand.grid()` so all combinations of `outcome` and `post` are found & extracted and then among them extract those that are `control==FALSE` (`tlist`: for `mpre1`,`sdpre1`,`n1`), and those that are `control==TRUE`(`clist`: for `mpre2`,`sdpre2`,`n2`).

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/q.csv")

m = split(data, data$study.name)

(mm = m["Dlsk_Krlr"])

(input <- lapply(mm, function(i) 
  rev(expand.grid(post = unique(i$post),outcome = unique(i$outcome)))))

res <- setNames(lapply(1:0, function(i) lapply(input, function(inp) Map(function(o, p)
  do.call(rbind, lapply(mm, function(x)
    x[x$control == i & x$post == p & x$outcome == o, , drop = FALSE])),
    inp$outcome, inp$post))), c("clist", "tlist"))

(aa = setNames(lapply(seq_along(res), function(i) Filter(NROW, res[[i]][[1]])), names(res)))
#== CURRENT OUPUT:
#$clist
#$clist[[1]]
#          study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome time_wk treats
#Dlsk_Krlr  Dlsk_Krlr     3 80 80.5  11.2 80.8  10.7    1    TRUE       1       1      2

#$clist[[2]]
#          study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome time_wk treats
#Dlsk_Krlr  Dlsk_Krlr     3 74 90.3   6.6 89.6   6.3    1    TRUE       2       1      2


#$tlist
#$tlist[[1]]
#              study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome time_wk treats
#Dlsk_Krlr.102  Dlsk_Krlr     1 73 81.6  10.8 83.1  11.1    1   FALSE       1       1      2
#Dlsk_Krlr.104  Dlsk_Krlr     2 72 81.4  10.9 85.0   8.1    1   FALSE       1       1      2

#$tlist[[2]]
#              study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome time_wk treats
#Dlsk_Krlr.103  Dlsk_Krlr     1 66 85.7  13.7 88.8  10.5    1   FALSE       2       1      2
#Dlsk_Krlr.105  Dlsk_Krlr     2 61 90.4   8.2 91.2   7.6    1   FALSE       2       1      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b <- lapply(aa, function(x)  {
           y<-do.call(rbind,  x)
          y[order(y$group), c("mpre", "sdpre", "n")] })
do.call(cbind.data.frame,rev(b))

             tlist.mpre tlist.sdpre tlist.n clist.mpre clist.sdpre clist.n
Dlsk_Krlr.102       81.6        10.8      73       80.5        11.2      80
Dlsk_Krlr.103       85.7        13.7      66       90.3         6.6      74
Dlsk_Krlr.104       81.4        10.9      72       80.5        11.2      80
Dlsk_Krlr.105       90.4         8.2      61       90.3         6.6      74
```

Comment: Onyambu, I had an interesting follow-up on your above answer. Imagine, `"mpre", "sdpre", "n"`  were all `NA`, using you solution can I get your final output with 4 rows and 6 columns but with all `NA` values?