# Follow-up: Extracting a data.frame from two lists in BASE R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, loops

I'm following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513402/7223434) answer. The output in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513402/7223434) works great (see below):

```
             tlist.mpre tlist.sdpre tlist.n clist.mpre clist.sdpre clist.n
Dlsk_Krlr.102       81.6        10.8      73       80.5        11.2      80
Dlsk_Krlr.103       85.7        13.7      66       90.3         6.6      74
Dlsk_Krlr.104       81.4        10.9      72       80.5        11.2      80
Dlsk_Krlr.105       90.4         8.2      61       90.3         6.6      74
```

However, I want to extract and add two columns named `nms = c('time_wk','treats')` from `data` to the above output. But the new output (see end of R code below) gets scrambled when I add `nms` to it.

Given my reproducible R code below is there a fix?

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/q.csv")

nms = c('time_wk','treats')

m = split(data, data$study.name)

(mm = m["Dlsk_Krlr"])


(input <- lapply(mm, function(i) 
  rev(expand.grid(post = unique(i$post),outcome = unique(i$outcome)))))

res <- setNames(lapply(1:0, function(i) lapply(input, function(inp) Map(function(o, p)
  do.call(rbind, lapply(mm, function(x)
    x[x$control == i & x$post == p & x$outcome == o, , drop = FALSE])),
  inp$outcome, inp$post))), c("clist", "tlist"))


(aa = setNames(lapply(seq_along(res), function(i) Filter(NROW, res[[i]][[1]])), names(res)))


b <- lapply(aa, function(x)  {
  y <- do.call(rbind,  x);
  y[order(y$group), c("mpre", "sdpre", "n", nms)] }) ## I'm adding `nms` HERE but that scrambles the output below

cc = do.call(cbind,rev(b))
cc_1 = cc[!duplicated(cc),]
names(cc_1)[1:6] = c('mT','sdT','nT','mC','sdC','nC')

### NEW SCRAMBLED OUTPUT AFTER ADDING `nms`:
#                mT  sdT nT mC sdC   nC clist.sdpre clist.n clist.time_wk clist.treats
#Dlsk_Krlr.102 81.6 10.8 73  1   2 80.5        11.2      80             1            2
#Dlsk_Krlr.103 85.7 13.7 66  1   2 90.3         6.6      74             1            2
#Dlsk_Krlr.104 81.4 10.9 72  1   2 80.5        11.2      80             1            2
#Dlsk_Krlr.105 90.4  8.2 61  1   2 90.3         6.6      74             1            2
```

Comment: What do you mean that it is scrambles? I see that it is similar to the previous results obtained

Comment: @jared_mamrot no. `nms` is a vector

Comment: That is a mistake you did when renaming. Not from the code. eg Type `cc` and look at the results.

Comment: just drop the other two columns `cc[grep("clist.(time_wk|treats)", names(cc), invert = TRUE)]`

Comment: yes, `cc[grep(sprintf("clist.(%s)", paste0(nms, collapse="|")), names(cc), invert = TRUE)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the base R solution:

```
cc[,grep(sprintf("clist.(%s)", paste0(nms, collapse="|")), names(cc), invert = TRUE)]
```

EDIT:

to ensure the nms comes the last:

```
d<-cc[grep(sprintf("clist.(%s)", paste0(nms, collapse="|")), names(cc), invert = TRUE)]

i1 <- grepl(sprintf("(%s)", paste0(nms, collapse="|")), names(d))

cbind(d[!i1], d[i1])
```

Comment: Its possible. @rnorouzian and you want that to be in base R?

Comment: save the results above as d for example, then use grep again to move the rows to the end.

Comment: @rnorouzian Edited